# Where in youtube file find tags/category_id I set during upload?

Tags: laravel, youtube

Using joedawson/youtube on laravel site I managed to upload a file
on youtube with tags/category_id defined

```
$video = Youtube::upload($fullPathToVideo, [
    'title'       => 'text',
    'description' => 'description ...',
    'tags'        => ['farBaz'],
    'category_id' => 10
]);
```

But checking uploaded video on youtube side : https://prnt.sc/a-x6hGOI8g78
I did not find information about tags/category_id I used...
Where can I find this info?

Can I filter all my uploaded files by tags/category_id ?

```
"dawson/youtube": "^2.0.1",
"laravel/framework": "^10.8",
```

Thanks in advance!